# Synology NAS performance as main disk for ESXi 5

Tags: vmware-esxi, network-attached-storage, synology

I'm planning on buying a Synology NAS, one of the + models.  I'm wondering what the performance would be like if I use it as the main disk for my ESXi 5 server. I mainly run Debian and run web and file servers.

I want to make an iscsi and mount it to ESXi and then create vmfs for my servers. The network is run on a switch with full gigabit bandwidth.

Thanks

Comment: Synology offers NAS from 200$ - 20 000$ so you should be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience there are two things to consider (currently using a 1512+).  One: If you plan on using this for a datastore, do not use WD red drives.  They are made for low IO mass storage.  Two: if you want to use link aggregation it does not work on Cisco switches (or at least not on the SG-x00 models.)  Beyond that all normal disk/raid level performance tips apply.